# CircleCI: $ npm test fails and doesn't find installed package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, mocha.js, circleci

For some reason Circle is not able to use `ts-mocha` installed with `npm install` in a previos step in the building process.

It used to work, but for some reason it doesn't anymore out of a sudden.

---

*This is the CircleCI build job result:*

[image: circle build job result]

*All tests are running fine locally:*

[image: local test run]

---

This is the script in the `package.json` that I run with `npm test`:

`"test": "env NODE_ENV=test ts-mocha ./test/**/*.spec.ts --timeout 10000"`

The package version is `"ts-mocha": "^6.0.0",`

This is my CircleCI job configuration (which hasn't changed in a month):

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.13.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run: npm install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
      - run: npm test
      - run: npx tsc
```

---

It seems that something broke from the Circle side, as there were no changes in the code.

Even though I tried rerunning old *successful* builds, they fail with this same error.

Things I tried:

- Running`npm ci && npm test` in the same step but it yields the same result.
- Removing `package-lock.json`
- Updating `package-lock.json`
- Running `npm install --no-package-lock`
- Updating npm
- Running `npm update`
- Running `npm audit fix`
- Cleaning npm cache

Also tried using `npx` instead of relying on the previously installed `ts-mocha` package and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there was an upstream change to `circleci/node:10.13.0` outside of CircleCI's control - it gets reported from time to time on their forum. To fix this temporarily, have a look at the Docker image digest in "Spin up environment" for your last successful build. It will be 40 characters long, I think. Then look at the digest for your first failed build, and see if it is different.

Comment: If it is different, then get the working one, and use `circleci/node:10.13.0@sha256:c8d8e642612872e5a9882c042341c35cbecf9e13d948e3a3bfcb9` (replacing the hash with your own). That is a temporary fix, since it does not resolve the underlying problem, but at least it gets your CI working again.

Comment: One you have that working, I would suggest getting a post-build SSH session and debugging it as if it were a local machine. The first thing I would do is see where the node modules have been installed to, and then what your current working dir is when you try running the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the CircleCI `NODE_ENV` environment variable was set to `production`, therefore any `devDependencies` were not getting installed (even with `npm install --save`, because it was already listed as a `devDependency` in the `package.json`).

I don't know when the environment variable was changed to that value, but the odd thing is that it started breaking from one day to another (although it should've been breaking since the moment that env variable was set) so it was extremely hard to debug, but it was a simple fix: changing the `NODE_ENV` environment variable in CircleCI to something different than `production`.